# how to Replace(dynamic) a specfic xml element using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

**Input xml**
This is the input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enc xmlns="v9">
   <rnp xmsns="v2">
      <ele1 line="1">
         <ele2/>
      </ele1>
   </rnp>
   <Request xmlns="v1">
      <Request xmlns="v2">
         <Info xmlns="v3">
            <Country>US</Country>
            <Part>A</Part>
         </Info>
      </Request>
   </Request>
</enc>
```

I want to replace "Request with namespce v1" with v2 tag.

XSL :
This is a xsl I have used.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:variable name="var1">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
        
            <xsl:when test="$var1='Request'">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="v2">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance .I am new to xsl

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "delete a specific tag". There are no tags in XSL transformation, only nodes. Please edit your question and add the expected result. Also show your current XSLT attempt, so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @michael ,i am learning xsl

Comment: Voted to close.

Comment: I have added xsl ,that i have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:v1="v1"
  exclude-result-prefixes="v1">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--  You namespaces do not have a prefix, just the URL.  So v1 would be considered 
        the URL (even though it doesn't look like one).  So, you have to declare your 
        namespace like I have above.  And, use the prefix in the template match.  
        Also, after transformation the child Request node will not have the v2 
        namespace shown because it inherits it from the parent Request node that was 
        just changed.  But, it is in the namespace.
  -->

  <xsl:template match="v1:Request">
    <xsl:element name="Request" namespace="v2">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```